# catkin system packages not specifying version number of ROS depe

Tags: ros, catkin, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit - I just upgraded to the release repository (1/29/2013)**

Reference: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Catkin system packages don't seem to be specifying the version number of their dependencies. For example, ros-groovy-pluginlib does not specify the version number for ros-groovy-class-loader. In contrast, all the rosbuild stacks seem fine.

When I did a full system update right now, almost everything got updated (including ros-groovy-pluginlib) because of a large number of rosbuild system packages. However the new version of ros-groovy-class-loader was not pulled in. Consequently, all of my code that uses pluginlib was broken until I upgraded ros-groovy-class-loader manually.

Thoughts?

**Edit#2**

I believe apt-get upgrade should work correctly. On the other hand calling apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full will not upgrade the dependencies correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53635/catkin-system-packages-not-specifying-version-number-of-ros-depe/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) on 2013-01-30**:
I do not have an answer currently, but I can confirm this issue happens  from time to time specifically with pluginlib and classloader (I maintain both). I have not been able to recreate the situation in which this happens, but it usually can be resolved by running sudo apt-get update/upgrade again.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-01-30**:
@mirzashah: I've filed a bug report against bloom: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/77. In the bug report, I try and give a slightly better explanation as to why I think this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I had misread your original question.

There is no version dependency right now as you have correctly noted, but it would not matter as bloom does not support it currently. I can add in a version dependency for pluginlib/class_loader now, but until that feature is implemented in bloom it won't help.

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1